# how invert __m128 into ints

Tags: c++, sse

```
float a[4] = {1,2,3,4}, b[4] = {4,3,2,1};
uint32_t c[4];

int main() {

    __m128 pa = _mm_loadu_ps(a);

    __m128 pb = _mm_loadu_ps(b);
    __m128 pc = _mm_cmpgt_ps(pa, pb);
    _mm_storeu_ps((float*)c, pc);
    for (int i = 0;i  < 4; ++i) printf("%u\n", c[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

what is the correct instruction of `_mm_storeu_ps((float*)c, pc)`?
here, c is a integer array... I don't think this way is good, any better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two instructions to convert `__m128` (`float` vector) into `__m128i` (`int32_t` vector) in SSE2: [`_mm_cvtps_epi32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdc42k5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)(with rounding) and [`_mm_cvttps_epi32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/1h005y6x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)(with truncation).

```
__m128i vi = _mm_cvttps_epi32(pc);
_mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)c, vi);
```

If you can't use SSE2, you should convert `float` array to `int` array after storing `pc` into `float` array.

```
float d[4];
_mm_storeu_ps(d, pc);
c[0] = (int)d[0]; c[1] = (int)d[1]; c[2] = (int)d[2]; c[3] = (int)d[3];
```